# Prove if it is a bijection.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Assume that g : **R** → **R** is a bijection and define f : **R** → **R** by

f(x) = 2g(x) + 1.

Determine, with proof, whether f is a bijection.

My opinion:

*I know that a function should either be increasing or decreasing in interval.
So if g(x) > 0, then f(x)>0
and if g(x)<0, then f(x)<0.
My thinking is that f(x) is either increasing or decreasing and hence it is also bijective.*

Comment: What's your intuition? Bijection or not?

Comment: I edited the question with what I think is the possible reasoning to whether the other function is bijective. Also I really appreciate the help

Comment: A bijective function is invertible and the composition of bijective functions is bijective. This is enough to determine if it's true or not. Note that it is not assumed that $g(x)$ is continuous so it can be any bijection and you won't necessarily be able to make any sense of increasing or decreasing on an interval because the function may not have any continuous parts at all.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I like your explanation. Is this all I need to know. Are there any additional things I should consider. I am curious to learn more

Comment: Can you prove that the conjunction of to bijective functions is bijetive?  Hint 2: if $g (x)=w $ then what is $v $ so that $g (v)=w $.  Is there always such a $v $? Is that $v $ unique?  And what does that all mean?

Comment: @AwakenedUser Another option is just to prove it straight from the definition. Show explicitly that it's injective and surjective and then conclude it's bijective. Also, if a function isn't surjective or injective you can restrict the range and domain respectively to force bijectivity on this restricted space. That can be useful at times.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you. I think I can better understand bijection now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go down the path of using derivatives for three reasons:

1. Functions may not be differentiable. It may make no sense to claim that $f'(x) > 0$ or $f'(x) < 0$.
2. Functions need not be continuous. While it is true that a continuous bijective function must be increasing or decreasing, this is not true for general functions. For example, the function
   $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if x = 0} \end{cases}$$
   is bijective, discontinuous, and neither increasing nor decreasing.
3. Even when the functions are strictly increasing or decreasing, this can only show the functions are one-to-one. You'd have to show they are onto in a different way. For example, the function
   $$f(x) = \arctan(x)$$
   is strictly increasing (hence one-to-one), but has a range of $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Hence it is not surjective, and hence not bijective.

---

Instead, simply use the definitions.

A function $f$ is one-to-one if, whenever $f(x) = f(y)$, we must have $x = y$. In our case, if we have $f(x) = f(y)$, then this means that $2g(x) + 1 = 2g(y) + 1$. By simplifying this equation, we get $g(x) = g(y)$. But, $g$ is also one-to-one, so we know the only way this can happen is if $x = y$. That is, when $f(x) = f(y)$, we have $x = y$, so $f$ is one-to-one, by definition.

A function $f$ is onto if, given any $y$, we can find an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. So, fix $y \in \Bbb{R}$. Let's find an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. That is, $2g(x) + 1 = y$. Solving this, we get $g(x) = \frac{y - 1}{2}$. Does there exist such an $x$? Yes, since $g$ is onto and $\frac{y - 1}{2} \in \Bbb{R}$. For this given value of $x$, rearranging the equation back again yields that $f(x) = 2g(x) + 1 = y$, which is what we want. Hence $f$ is onto.

Comment: I like the information you provided. I am learning more from the post. Thank you.

Comment: @AwakenedUser You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=f(y)$ then $2g(x)+1=2g(y)+1\implies g(x)=g(y)$ and since $g$ is injective, $x=y$. Therefore, $f$ is injective.

Let $r\in\mathbb R$. Then, since $g$ is surjective, there exists $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $g(x)=\frac{r-1}{2}$. Then $f(x)=2g(x) + 1=2(\frac{r-1}{2})+1=r$ so $f$ is surjective.

Therefore, $f$ is a bijection.